# INSERT Multiple Records From A DataGridView Using CheckBox In Database

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I have the function (Code) below to insert some data in DB , but i'd like to know how can i change it to INSERT Multiple Records From A DataGridView Using a CheckBox . I don't  want lose my function -  Public Function Pagamentos() 
but, integrate a method to insert data from multiple selected data in datagridview

```
Public Function Pagamentos() As Boolean
    Dim cd As New NpgSqlCommand
Dim query As String = ""
  Try

     query &= " INSERT INTO Caixa (Recibo, CentroCusto, Data, Dia, Mes, Ano, CentroCustoResumo,DescricaoCentroCusto,CodSubCentroCusto,DescSubCentroCusto,Eventos,Historico,Dinheiro,Cheque,Cartao,DepositoDireto,Total) "
        query &= String.Format(" VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}') ", iRecibo, sCentroCusto, sData, sDia, sMes, sAno, sCentroCustoResumo, sDescricaoCentroCusto, sCodSubCentroCusto, sDescSubCentroCusto, sEventos, sHistorico, sDinheiro, sCheque, sCartao, sDepositoDireto, sTotal)

      cd.CommandText = query
        cd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        If Conexao.NonQuery(cd) Then
           sStatus = "Dados do Recibo " & iRecibo & " inserido com sucesso!"
          Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        sStatus = ex.Message
   End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Something like this
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/delete-multiple-record-from-a-datagridview-using-checkbox-i/

Comment: How did the data get "into" the DGV?  The sane way to do all of that in small apps is to let the NET DB Provider objects do it for you.  Use a DataSaource and let your DataAdapter update the DB for you - hundreds of add/change/deletes all at once.  That would prevent that dreadful way of forming SQL.  I dont speak whatever that is, but it is doubtfull every single field is text, but that is what you are passing,.

Comment: Lose that function. Use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid, then use the same data adapter to save the changes.  It's not even clear what "Using a CheckBox" means in this scenario. `CheckBoxes` don't save data so it is literally impossible. Try explaining what you actually mean.

Comment: create a loop and insert more data?